# How we can solve this differential equation $y'=x^2 e^{x^3}-\ln(y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the way to solve this differential equation :

$$y'=x^2 e^{x^3}-\ln(y^2)$$

I thought at start to make it exact but I got no luck there for the factor , Does it need series or Laplace? May anyone please tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha nor Mathematica were able to find any closed forms. I'd suggest not losing sleep over this.

Comment: @K.defaoite well, maybe you can find a solution in terms of special functions or as a power series. The key is to know where this equation comes from, because if it is from a book there must be some way to study it, in other case.... It does not look solvable.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was so bad to not know the solution , good to know it is not solvable in easy way, I dont know originally from where I saw it on board and I couldnt figure it out . Thanks

Comment: Laplace-transforms can only be used for linear problems, the $\ln(y^2)$ breaks this.